# How to clear the contents of global roArray in brightscript?

Tags: brightscript

I created roArray and added to global scope as given below

```
columnSize = CreateObject("roArray", 3 , true)
m.global.addFields({guideColumnSize: columnSize})
```

and I am adding the values into guideColumnSize as given below

```
columnSize = m.global.guideColumnSize
columnSize[x] = adjustColumn
```

I am able to print after adding the values. I have added 5 values of 48. But I am unable to clear, delete or modify the values in the array. These requests are getting ignored.

I tried

```
m.global.guideColumnSize.delete(0)
m.global.guideColumnSize.clear()
m.global.guideColumnSize[0] = 2
```

Nothing is working. Only operation I can perform is appending the values at the end of the array. Can any one please let me know how can we modify or clear the contents of global roArray in brightscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear or delete the global variable in brightscript, use the following code

```
m.global.guideColumnSize = invalid
```

or

```
m.global.setFields({guideColumnSize : invalid})
```

You can reinitialize the roArray object and store it to the same global variable

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify elements within an array/associative array in the global node directly. You have to access the object, modify it and save it back into the global field (see [SceneGraph data scoping](https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/developer-program/core-concepts/data-scoping.md#global-scope) for further details).

Assuming the same structure as your example, you could do the following:

```
columnSize = [1, 2, 3]
m.global.addFields({guideColumnSize: columnSize})

newColumnSize = m.global.guideColumnSize
newColumnSize[1] = 0
m.global.guideColumnSize = newColumnSize
```

Printing `m.global.guideColumnSize` will return `[1, 0, 3]`.

You were just missing the step of reassigning the modified array back to the global field.

To clear a global node field you can use `m.global.removeField("guideColumnSize")` or simply set `m.global.guideColumnSize = invalid`.